# Can't translate year(s)word for recurring contributions

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, translation

in CiviContribute Recurring Contributions I can't translate the *Year(s)* word. I don't find it in PoEdit files. Word replacing doesn't work. Any ideas?

[image]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

This is a longstanding problem with no easy solution. See for example https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/issues/53

Comment: Let's hope that they fix it!